# How would you handle a merge if there's 2 tags on the same branch and you need to update/commit changes to the first tag?

Tags: git, merge

Say you have 2 tags on the same branch (tags A + B), where A is on a commit before B.

```
 A ----> B
```

Say now you are working on a change on Tag A, and you want to merge this patch on the same branch but with Tag-A (because existing build-scripts are pointing to this singular branch).  How would you go about merging, while having the latest changes that are done to Tag A but exclude Tag B?  It's okay to have a new tag named Tag C, but that needs to be the head.

Obviously in an ideal world, you wouldn't have merged Tag A + Tag B on the same branch if additional changes to Tag A were to be isolated from Tag B changes.

Comment: In general, the correct way is: *never change any tag, ever.* The *idea* behind a tag is that it names a fixed point: some specific commit, forever. That's the key difference between a branch name and a tag name: we *expect* branch names to point to newer commits all the time, but we *expect* tag names to remain static. (There are some exceptions to this rule, but they amount to either "no one else has this tag yet" or "sorry, I goofed, everyone else please make note of my goof".)

Comment: You haven't mentioned any branch. When you say "merge" what do you mean? Merge what branch to what? I think I have an answer but I'd like to make I understand your question.